# Android complex Serializable object - simple how to

Tags: android, serializable

I'm looking at making an custom Android object `Serializable`.  Should be simple I just cannot find a easy way to do this.  I get the fact that I must overload `writeObject` and `readObject`... just how do write and read this I don't get.  Beginner here ...

```
public class QObject implements Serializable  {

public String lq_a;
public String lq_b;
Vector lq_vec;

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    //should I go one by one a output each element?  
    out.writeBytes(lq_a);

    //or is there a simpler way?  Like write this object one liner?
    out.writeObject(this); 

    //should I close the ObjectOutputStream?
    out.close(); 
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    //baffled here ... how do I read this object?
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you thing you need to override read/writeoObject()? There is nothing special about your class, just have it implement `Serializable` and you are done.

Comment: OK I found my mistake looking at the page below I got the impression I needed to overload the two functions. It is not the case, for future newbies just add the implements Serializable and your done.   http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: OK I found my mistake looking at the page below I got the impression I needed to overload the two functions. It is not the case, for future newbies just add the implements Serializable and your done. This works well when you want to pass a complex object to a new activity.



http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html